# How do I stop blitted text from disappearing in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make it so that when a sprite on the screen is in a specific place, some text has to be blitted on the screen at a certain place but when my sprite reaches the place the text is blitted for just a fraction of a second and it disappears, why is this happening and how do I fix it, i've attached concerned part of my code below and the full code with prerequisite files is [here](https://github.com/Batsy24/Pokemon-red.git)

```
def attack():
    cursorX = 230
    cursorY = 435
    A1 = font.render('Thundershock', True, black)
    A2 = font.render('Quick Attack', True, black)
    A3 = font.render('Growl', True, black)
    A4 = font2.render('Electric', True, yellow)
    A5 = font2.render('Normal', True, grey)
    running = True
    while running:
        scr.fill(black)
        scr.blit(attack_scr, (70, 0))
        scr.blit(Flareon, (470, 0))
        scr.blit(A1, (270, 435))
        scr.blit(A2, (270, 470))
        scr.blit(A3, (270, 505))
        scr.blit(Cursor, (cursorX, cursorY))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if cursorY <= 535 and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    cursorY += 35
                if cursorY >= 470 and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    cursorY += -35
                if cursorY == 435:
                    scr.blit(A4, (265, 310))
                else:
                    scr.blit(A5, (265, 310))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw the text in the main application loop, dependent on a state which is set when the event occurs:

```py
def attack():
    # [...]

    drawA4 = False
    drawA5 = False
 
    running = True
    while running:
        # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # [...]

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if cursorY <= 535 and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    cursorY += 35
                if cursorY >= 470 and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    cursorY += -35
                if cursorY == 435:
                    drawA4 = True
                else:
                    drawA5 = True

        if drawA4:
            scr.blit(A4, (265, 310))
        if drawA5:
            scr.blit(A5, (265, 310))
 
        # [...]
```